# tibble rename does not persist - new names revert their old names

Tags: r, rename, tibble

If I create a simple tibble and rename one of the variables:
test<-tibble(a=1:2,b=3:4)
rename(test,c=a)
then it shows, as expected, the new variables c and b
but if I print the tibble again, the variables have reverted to their old names a,b.
What am I doing wrong? thanks.
[tibble rename fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7wat.png)

Answer (score 0):

You will want to overwrite the tibble when doing rename, so the following:

`test <- rename(test,c=a)`